# AssertionError when unit testing an annotation processor with compile-testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, annotation-processing

Google's [compile-testing](https://github.com/google/compile-testing) is a great tool when it comes to unit testing annotation processors. Unfortunately I'm currently facing the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
An expected source declared one or more top-level types that were not present.

Expected top-level types: <[test.LocalStorage]>
Declared by expected file: <LocalStorageImpl.java>

The top-level types that were present are as follows: 

- [test.LocalStorageImpl] in </SOURCE_OUTPUT/test/LocalStorageImpl.java>
```

My processor generates the implementation of an annotated interface. So the generated code has a dependency to the interface (`class LocalStorageImpl implements LocalStorage`).

When I try to verify the generated code with

```
    JavaFileObject source = /* interface definition */
    JavaFileObject expected_source = /* the generated implementation */

    assertAbout(javaSource()).that(source)
    .processedWith(new MyProcessor())
    .compilesWithoutError()
    .and()
    .generatesSources(expectedSource);
```

...the `generatesSource` causes the error. As the error message states, it cannot resolve the interface definition.

**So my question is how to compile or write the source file of the interface defined in `source`, so that it is recognized by `generatesSources()`?**

Comment: Are all your source files generated via `this.processingEnv.getFiler().createSourceFile(name, originatingElements)`?

Comment: I'm using JavaPoet's `JavaFile.writeTo(Filer filer)`, which calls `filer.createSourceFile(fileName, originatingElements.toArray(...));` under the hood. So, yes, it seems all source files are generated like you mentioned. (https://github.com/square/javapoet/blob/master/src/main/java/com/squareup/javapoet/JavaFile.java)

Comment: Yes it is the same issue we are have. My initial guess is that generated files are not visible to the classloader.  They do not appear to have a test for this use case even though it is in their documentation.

Comment: I have created an [issue] (https://github.com/google/compile-testing/issues/83) for this problem.